# Saving a combobox id instead of the text

Tags: sql, vb.net

Good morning people, or rather midnight.
I am totally new (again) to programming since I had to drop college for years due a lack of economic power and started fresh over,hence after several years I have forgotten almost everything.

Here is the thing though, I never thought I would have problem with a simple insert into. I am using visual basic and I am trying to save the following sentence in a database

```
Dim insertQuery As String = "INSERT INTO Camion (Plate, BrandID , ModelID, Year, Engine, Chasis, WeightLimit ,DateofPurchase) VALUES ('" & txtplate.Text & "','" & cmbBrand.Text & "','" & cmbModel.Text & "','" & Year.Value & "','" & txtEngine.Text & "','" & txtChasis.Text & "','" & nudWeightLimit.Value & "','" & dtpDateofPurchase.Value & "')"

ExecuteQuery(insertQuery)
MessageBox.Show("Info succesfully saved")
```

Now here is the issue. My combo box shows the name of the items instead of the code which is ok, I want it to do this so that people know what they are selecting. However, at the time of saving, this goes into a table where it only saves the ID of the combo box (not where it draws the data but a 2nd table where it stores all this info) but the sentence I am showing tries to save the Text displayed in the combo box in a int type of field in the database.

I am using mysql. So that is basically my issue, when I try to save the combo box of let's say brand , on the display list it shows Nissan and Mercedes. (in the database where it pulls that info, nissan is id 1, and mercedes is id 2). So it shows the name on the list as intended so people knows what they are selecting, but when I try to save it. I end up saving the name in a INT field, which shouldn't happen, is there a way to get the ID from the combobox and save that in the database?

Sorry if the question seems terribly silly as I am sure there is a easy solution but I haven't found one, even with google.

Comment: Are you using Windown.Forms?

Comment: `combobox.value` and `combobox.text` also `combobox.index` try figure out what those do and I think you can get the right value to insert.

Comment: Can you add some screenshot ?

Comment: You should be binding an appropriate list to your `ComboBoxes` and setting the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. If you have done that right then you get the value you want from the `SelectedValue` property. By the way, you should learn how to use parameterised queries. There are all sorts of real and potential issues with that code.